# Storing sensor data on very small iot device for 5 days before downloading the data

Tags: sensors

We have a small battery driven IoT device that is collecting data from 3 bio sensors.

We need to store this data on the little device for 5 days.

The main MCU is a Max32660. Would love to get some recommendations on the strategies of how to solve this.

Comment: How much data are we talking about? How much per reading, how frequent are the readings? How are you the "downloading" the data? Wired connection to an external device? Upload to a server? You haven't given us a lot of information here...

Comment: Also what is the battery life (is it the 5 days you mentioned?), does the data need to be preserved if the battery goes flat? Also how are the sensors connected (so we know which of the SPI/I2C/UART busses are already consumed)